# What algorithm is used by ARKit or ARCore to detect planar surfaces?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I am working on creating simple AR applications and I played a bit with both ARCore and ARKit. I was impressed by the accuracy of the positioning of virtual objects in the real world, since the phones I played with do not have depth sensor nor multiple cameras, so I was wondering:
what algorithm do these SDKs implement for plane detection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Basically, ARCore uses a technique called [Concurrent Odometry and Mapping](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/concepts) (**COM**) and ARKit uses a technique called [Visual-Inertial Odometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/understanding_world_tracking) (**VIO**) to understand where the smartphone is relative to the real environment around it.

At first stage – **Motion Tracking** – each smartphone combines visual data coming from **`RGB camera sensor`** (at 60 fps) and motion data coming from **`accelerometer and gyroscope sensors`** (at 1000 fps) to compute a position of a high-contrast `feature points` using [parallax formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax). That information allows ARCore and ARKit get a position and orientation of a virtual camera in six degrees of freedom (6 DoF).

The next stage – **Scene Understanding** – helps ARCore and ARKit understand where several feature points (a.k.a. sparse point cloud) are coplanar – thus, letting a smartphone find out where a detected plane will be.

The last ARCore's stage is **Light Estimation** and the last ARKit's stage is **Rendering** (**`you don't even need to import SceneKit`** because ARKit contains all the necessary SceneKit's classes – check this out).

> As you can see, there's no need for manufacturer to supply a smartphone with multiple `RGB cameras` or with `Depth rear camera` because just ***RGB and IMU sensors can do the job***.

Comment: Hey Andy, I like your answer as it summarizes really well how both technologies work, but do you have a source that says that Rendering is the last stage of ARKit? In my head, it doesn’t make sense, since ARKit is basically a framework for scene understanding, which is “unrelated” to how it’s rendered (e.g., we could use ARKit to get scene info and render with Metal or Vulkan).

Comment: Hey @MarcelAlves, please watch ARKit WWDC 2017 session (time 05:00) about `ARKit's 3rd layer` coming after `Scene Understanding`. Since ARKit in Xcode contains all necessary SceneKit's classes you don't even need to import SceneKit module when you're making iOS AR app. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/602